# Python readlines() only working with the last line in txt file

Tags: python

Im trying to make a python script that will change a password based on the day of the week, but whenever I use the if function to see if the password I typed matches the password on the file it always comes back as false. I've noticed that it only comes back as true when I have it check my typed password to the line of text on the file.

Code:

```
passwords = open('passwords.txt', "r")
content = passwords.readlines()
userpassword = input()


if userpassword == content[x]:
    print('same')
else:
    print('different')
```

passwords.txt:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

So when I change x in the content to 0,1 or 2 and input the corresponding password it will always output 'different', but if x is changed to 3 and I enter the right password it will output 'same'. It also doesnt matter how many passwords I have in the txt file, it will only output 'same' if I change x to the number that corresponds with the last line in the txt file while also imputing the same password

Comment: In general, people often use lots of print statements to help debug code. In this case, you could `print(contents)` after the readlines() and you'll see extra characters you might want to strip. You can also print content[x]  (and also userpassword) to see what you're comparing. To strip whitespace, check out [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip). You can tack this onto content[x] so it becomes `content[x].strip()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Carriage return` are in every string of your `content` list (except the last one) and doesn't allow the match with `userpassword`.

You could do `content = open("passwords.txt",'r').read().splitlines()` to remove those `\n`.